# What is the scope of moment.tz.setDefault() when used in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, datetime, meteor, timezone, momentjs

**TL;DR What is the scope of `moment.tz.setDefault()`?**

I'm sure my problem here stems from my inexperience with both JavaScript and Meteor but I've been struggling with the problem for several straight days now.

I'm working on an app that must take into account the client's timezone but I'm having significant difficulty in forcing the server code to use the client's timezone. Somewhere along the way--that being from the moment the client presses "Submit" to the moment Meteor inserts--my timezone setting is getting lost and local time (of the server) is being used.

The app flow is like this:

1. (client) user submits form
2. (client) validation of data is performed
3. (server) Meteor method is called
4. (server) validation of data is performed (same code as earlier)
5. (server) business logic is applied
6. (server) insert into DB

I capture the timezone at step 1 and *try* to pass it along through all the steps but I must be missing something because between 4 and 5 the timezone is (seemingly) lost. The fast is, I'm not seeing why. I've checked this 100 times and tried all manner of different permutations but can't figure out where the gap is (I've used soooo many `console.log()`s it's crazy.)

So instead of trying to set the timezone at every point `Moment()` is used (because it defaults to calculating in local time) I discovered `moment.tz.setDefault()` and tried using that at least once on each .js file in my app. But it didn't work.

Reading this it might sound like I'm not doing enough testing but that is not the case. I have spent 10s of hours on this and I'm just not getting it. I'd love to share the code but I think it's just too long and complicated to properly share so I've done my best to explain the problem.

Comment: [Have you read this great article from Josh already](http://joshowens.me/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript/) ?

Comment: I haven't but I'm going to read it now. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out I'm already doing these things. Well... sort of. I'm not capturing the client's timezone at registration, rather my intent is to capture it from the client during submission of a new event and store it (the timezone) alongside the event.

Comment: I think important is that you capture events on the client with their respective time zones and then submit it with the offset translation to the server as UTC. This is how I'm doing it the last 15 years especially in my industry (Marine  & Offshore) it is of utmost importance to keep time offset-save.

Comment: My difficulty is that I'm actually accepting a range (start/stop) and comparing those values to other periods (Does it begin in valid period? Does it stop in valid period?) So I'm trying to keep the timezones consistent because the "valid period" is a person's workday start/stop time which is "day" agnostic. Which is why my original question is about the scope of moment.tz.setDefault(). I may be overcomplicating it as, Matt K suspects, but I'm also not just simply receiving one datetime value and storing it.

Comment: See edited answer, this is pretty much a copy & paste from a current project of mine that requires the same thing. No moment.js needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! You're overcomplicating it :-)

Open up a browser console & type `time = new Date()`. Notice how it's in the correct timezone? That's because the timezone conversion is happening on the client.

Now, type `time.valueOf()`. As you probably know, you've got the number of milliseconds since 1-1-1970...but in what timezone?? You guessed it, UTC!

So if all you're doing is saving a number, and the client is fully capable of converting that number into the local timezone, why not save the time in UTC on the server? You'll get an ISODate() in your database (which is a fancy int64). Then, when you retrieve it on the client, you can put it in their local time (they might be traveling!) or any other timezone you chose. If it's a meetup in a certain city, simply grab the timezone of that city & apply it to the field. Hint: THIS is the appropriate time to use moment.js, not before!

---

Edit for time patterns:

Based on the new info, I imagine you have something that accepts an `arrivalTime` & then makes sure the time is between an `earlyArrival` and `lateArrival` say, 7:00 - 8:30AM. So, save the times as dates

```
timeToDate = function(time) {
  return new Date('1970 1 1 ' + time);
};
earlyArrival = timeToDate('7:30 AM');
arrivalTime = timeToDate('8:00 AM');
lateArrival = timeToDate('8:30 AM');
```

Then, validate via simple math: `earlyArrival < arrivalTime`.

OR, if you use simple schema (which you should), a validation pattern might look like this:

```
departureTime: {
  type: Date,
  min: timeToDate('5:00 PM'),
  max: timeToDate('6:30 PM'),
  autoValue: function() {
    return timeToDate(this.value);
  },
  custom: function () {
    if (this.value < this.field('arrivalTime').value) {
      return "lateAfterEarly";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to need to take some time to digest this as it's quite different from how my brain has been spinning. But I'm hopeful! :)

Comment: Lots of good info here. The timeToDate() is especially helpful because it's something I had thought of but couldn't figure out how to execute. Ugh... I think I should maybe start over with this part. Also, I've never heard of Simple Schema but it looks great. But... can I accept this as an answer since it doesn't really answer the question? If someone later comes across this they'll be sorely disappointed.

Comment: JavaScript is function scoped, so your question kiiiinda doesn't make sense :-). `setDefault` changes the `moment.defaultZone` variable.

Comment: You may need additional logic if you could cross midnight.  Say you arrive at 23:00 but latest arrival is 01:00.

Comment: Also, the validation logic on the *server* will need to compare against times that are valid for the server's time zone, or UTC.  You wont be able to use the same validation logic on both client and server.  This answer only addresses client validation.

Comment: @MattJohnson I've been able to work out my problem (at least that's what all my tests have shown.) This is a time off tracker for employees so time diffs are always between the start/stop of a person's work day. When you say "won't be able to use same validation logic" do you mean through Simple Schema? Because I am using the same logic (but not using Simple Schema.)

Comment: I'm not sure of your specific needs, but I've worked on plenty of time trackers that are used by employees that work night shifts that cross midnight.  Something to think about.

Comment: What I meant was that in your steps 2 and 4 in the question, you validate with the same time-based logic on the client and again on the server.  On the client, you can take Matt K's approach, because the client code is aware of the client's time zone.  But on the server, by default you don't know the client's time zone unless you're capturing it somewhere else in the application.